# How to get the list of files in the GCS Bucket using the Jupyter notebook in Dataproc?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc

I have recently started using GCP for my project and encountered difficulties when working with the bucket from the Jupyter notebook in the Dataproc cluster. At the moment I have a bucket with a bunch of files in it, and a Dataproc cluster with the Jupyter notebook. What I am trying to do is go over all the files in the bucket and extract the data from them to create a dataframe.

I can access one file at a time with the following code: `data = spark.read.csv('gs://BUCKET_NAME/PATH/FILENAME.csv')`, but there are hundreds of files, and I cannot write a line of code for each of them. Usually, I would do something like this:

`import os`
`for filename in os.listdir(directory):`
    `...`

but this does not seem to work here. So, I was wondering, how do I iterate over files in a bucket using Jupyter notebook in the Dataproc cluster?

Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can list the elements in your bucket with the following commands:

```
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client()
BUCKET_NAME = 'your_bucket_name'
bucket = client.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
elements = bucket.list_blobs()
files=[a.name for a in elements]
```

If there are no folders in your bucket, the list called files will contain the names of the files.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped! I have also read more about this function, and, just for future readers, it is not necessary to create a `bucket` here. `client.list_blobs(BUCKET_NAME)` also works