# Read images from a bucket in GCP for ML

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-lab, bucket, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have created a bucket in GCP containing my images dataset.

The path to it is: xray-competition-bucket/img_align_celeba

How do I read it from GCP to Jupyter Lab in Vertex AI?

My code is:

```
MAIN_PATH = '/gcs/xray-competition-bucket/img_align_celeba'

image_paths = glob((MAIN_PATH + "/*.jpg"))
```

and the result is that image_paths is an empty array.

Note: I also tried the path gs://my_bucket/...

Comment: I also used tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(MAIN_PATH,...) and got an error saying that "No such file or directory".

Comment: Can you share your dependencies?

Comment: @DanielCohen Similar post regarding [reading files from GCS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67520854/how-to-get-the-list-of-files-in-the-gcs-bucket-using-the-jupyter-notebook-in-dat). You can also go though this article regarding [image classification](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/how-to-classify-images-with-tensorflow-using-google-cloud-machine-learning-and-cloud-dataflow). If this does not help you please add a brief description of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to [download the GCS file locally](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-python) using `gsutil` or the python SDK if you want to use glob. There are also libraries like [GCSFS](https://gcsfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or TensorFlow's [GFile](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/gfile/GFile) which offer a pythonic file-system interface for working with GCS. For example, here is [GFile.glob](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/gfile/glob).